# Open parenthesis followed by j produces "crash" (slight overlap of glyphs)

Tags: fonts, kerning

Using the [Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/) font in a large dictionary project, the open parenthesis and lower case Roman j glyphs are often in contact, and my proofreader has asked me to fix the problem, which she calls a "crash". I've tried inserting a small space manually in these places, but I wonder if there's another solution. Italics are not involved, so I see that italic correction will not work, but perhaps there is something similar for inappropriate touching between ( and j?

The text is `raggedright`; I'd prefer not to make any substantial changes to the rest of the code.

Example:

```
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
...
to inlay (\tiny{~}\normalsize jewels
to inlay (jewels
...
```

[image]

Comment: This should probably be reported to the developers of the TeX Gyre fonts. `\kern.1em` would probably be better than `\tiny{~}\normalfont`, however.

Comment: `\tiny` does not take an argument so `(\tiny{~}\normalsize j` would be better written as `({\tiny~}j` but better still would be something like `(\kern0.1em j` so it automatically adjusted to the current font size. The more automatic (but more involved) version would be to modify or make a vf file that adjusted the font metrics to add a kern. (I think xetex or luatex could do this without making a vf file)

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, but how do I report an issue to the font developers?

Comment: The documentation says to contact Bogusław Jackowski: `B_Jackowski` AT `gust` DOT `org` DOT `pl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, provided by @egreg and @David Carlisle in comments, is to use

```
(\kern0.1em j
```

Works like a dream; actually exactly like a dream. Here's a comparison of the outputs; the manual kerning is second.

[image]